# Who sings 'Embrace the Heresy'?

Tags: league-of-legends

League of Legends recently released their newest champion, Diana - The Scorn of the Moon.  To promote and celebrate this event, they've updated their launcher's splash screen and background music. Additionally the background music now sports lyrics.(for the first time to my knowledge)

Some searching has taught me that the song is titled [Embrace the Heresy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjgwN_cRt2c), but I cannot find who the vocalist of the song is. **Who is she?**

Comment: The song is very similar to the elven songs from TLOTR, perhaps the same vocalist?

Comment: Has similarities but doesn't sound like Enya. Don't know though, someone unknown with lots of computer modifications probably.

Comment: @Dbemerlin was enya who sung the TLOTR elven songs? I didn't know that, although now that you mention it, it does sound like her.

Comment: Related http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5746/questions-that-are-only-loosely-related-to-gaming-are-on-topic

Comment: @Michel Ayres As I understand it , the highest voted and accepted answer in the linked meta argument supports that this question is on-topic.

Comment: @Ender No, the answer is saying that these questions are not the same as ITGs.  The fact remains that this is not a gaming problem.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot but as Bapd has said, we are a QnA site first, and problem solving site second. Tons of our questions are not about problems. TONS.

Comment: @Ender We are a Q&A site about _gaming_.The question is not about gaming.  It doesn't matter whether it is a problem or not.  Identifying music has no part in playing LoL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The vocalist goes by the name Saiyaka and she is a graphic designer for Riot Games. She posted [here](http://saiyaka.tumblr.com/post/28912137474/this-is-really-my-voice-omgomgomgomgomg-im-so) on her tumblr about it, along with a link to the following video:

You can find other posts on the official boards referring to her singing [here](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=27957789#27957789) and [here](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=27936052#post27936052):

> Fun fact: The graphic designer who sang this song also made the unique targeting reticle for Diana's Q. :)

In addition, you can check the official League of Legends soundcloud [here](http://soundcloud.com/leagueoflegends) for the song.